# Linq-to-Entities - can I reference the many-to-many link table directly?

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a many-to-many table linking the **User** and **Company** table, it also holds a BIT value *IsApproved* - but L2E is not allowing me to access that value - is there any way to get this value easily?  Thank you.

**Link Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE UserCompany
(
    UserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL REFERENCES User(Id),
    CompanyId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Company(Id),
    IsApproved BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (UserId, CompanyId)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your EDMX model is not updated: you'll have the UserCompany as a separate entity because it contains a column besides the foreign keys.

Please try the following:

- Check out that the connection string is pointing to correct database
- Delete the relationship and update model from database

Comment: Strange, I had to delete everything then reload to get it to recognize.  Thank you.